# Order scope results by closest match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-7

I have three models: Doctor, Appointment, Patient. A Doctor has many patients through appointments and a Patient has many doctors, also through appointments.

I have a search query where you can filter doctors by patients, so if you input the names of the patients it will show you any doctor that has assigned any of those patients.

Here is the scope I use to search within the Doctor model:

```
scope :by_patient, lambda { |*names|
    names_array = names.map { |name| "%#{name}%" }
    joins(appointments: :patient).where('lower(patients.name) LIKE ANY (array[?])', names_array)
}
```

> E.g.
>
> Dr. Smith -> Patients: Karen, Joe, Kate, Mary
>
> Dr. Johnson -> Patients: Kate, Mary
>
> Dr. Spears -> Patients: John
>
> If you look for Patients Kate and Mary the query will return both
> Dr. Smith and Dr. Johnson, however, Dr. Smith should be shown first
> because he has both patients while Dr. Johnson only has one.

How could I order the search results by those doctors who have the most patients?

Comment: You gave listed 2 rails versions (both are very old) please clarify what version you are using, as well as what version of mySQL as these are pertinent details needed to answer your question appropriately.

Comment: Updated in the question, I'm using Rails 7.0.4 and postgresql (gem version 1.1)

Comment: Try this: `joins(appointments: :patient).where('lower(patients.name) LIKE ANY (array[?])', names_array).group(:id).order(Patient.arel_table[:id].count.desc)`

Comment: @engineersmnky looks like it works! could you please add an explanation to better understand what it is doing? thank you!

Comment: It adds `GROUP BY "doctors"."id" ORDER BY COUNT("patients".*) DESC` to the query.

Comment: What @max said. Additionally please note: in your example "Dr. Smith" and "Dr. Johnson" both have Kate and Mary as patients (might want to fix the example)  so their "count" will be 2 and the order will be less determinable in this case.

Comment: I gotta say that this might very likely fall into one of those cases where you should'nt be using LIKE in the first place and where it will give results that are not what the user wanted. If I was looking up doctors by patient I would want to be VERY sure that I'm actually using the correct patient and not just some random person with a similiar name. If you want to let the users look up patients by name then do it in a way so that they can verify the results and then use the id of the patient in the rest of your application.